# Можно найти есть ли в массиве массив по первому значению "подмассива"?

Tags: javascript, массивы

У нас есть массив

```
array = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Нужно узнать, есть ли внутри массива array массив, чей первый элемент = 1.

Можно ли это сделать без перебора массива?

Comment: "Без перебора" это без явного заглядывания в каждый элемент и сравнения значений?

Comment: Без ручного заглядывания

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если цель именно "без for или while":

```js
let arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]];

console.log( JSON.stringify(arr).includes("[1") );
// Приводит к строке "[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]" и ищет совпадение с "[1"

console.log( arr.some(e => e[0] === 1) );
// Вернет true если хотя бы у одного подмассива, [0]-й элемент будет == 1

console.log( arr.find(e => e[0] === 1) );
// Вернет первый найденный подмассив
```

Но всё равно во всех примерах происходит перебор.

Comment: Через JSON - хорош. Ещё такой можно `/\[1/.test(JSON.stringify(array))` для минимизации.